# How to see errors in MySQL Workbench 6.1?

Tags: mysql-workbench

I recently upgraded my development machine to use MySQL Workbench 6.1.  I am trying to enter some data into a table using the workbench and "Select rows..."  When I click the "Apply" button to insert the data, the workbench reports that an error occurred (see the image below), but it doesn't tell me what the error is.  Workbench 5.* used to show the errors.  I cannot find any way to get Workbench 6.1 to show me the errors.  How can I see the error messages?

[image: Screen shot of MySQL Workbench stating an error occurred but not showing the error message]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To cause MySQL Workbench to show error messages, I had to change a preference.  From the Workbench menu, click "Edit" -> "Preferences..."  Open the "SQL Queries" tab.  Check "Confirm Data Changes".

Comment: I eventually worked out that the panel could be opened by hovering my mouse at just the top of the status bar (at the bottom of the UI).

Answer (score 80):

If you are on linux machine this solution will work.
It is already there you have to move your mouse and expand it:
At first it will look like this:
[image: initial state]

you have to hover the mouse until the cursor icon change to resize icon.upward
[image]

then click it and pull 
[image]

and then you can hover on cross sign scroll right to see the error message completely. 
[image]

Comment: Thank you for sharing this! I wasn't seeing it either.

Comment: The answer is not valid for this question, but it's a lifesaver for many souls who are searching to find errors in workbench. Thanks.

Comment: Are you kidding me lol. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, but i tried for minutes, the resize icon didn't want to appear!! I really think one pixel height is waaaay tooo thin as a landing area!! Still the same in WorkBench 8.0

Comment: Also, make sure to try to find the area on the right side of the GUI, the left side doesn't give you the resize cursor. For me it was one line going all the way from the left to the right. But they are actually two lines belonging to two different windows. I just didn't notice because they were perfectly aligned.

Answer (score 24):

I eventually worked out that the panel could be opened by hovering my mouse at just the top of the status bar (at the bottom of the UI).

The hit area is tiny so you really have to 'feel' around for the drag point.

Comment: I wonder why it's still the same in 2019 - MySQL Workbench 8?

Comment: because its a bit of a crappy product :<

Answer (score 5):

If you are not seeing any sql errors or exceptions this could be one off your problems.
Toggle the button in the picture
[button panel of mysqlworkbench](https://i.stack.imgur.com/myNcy.png)